# What could be causing my Ruby application to only download a 1 KB file when trying to get a video from a private S3 bucket?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ruby

We have an S3 private bucket, and the objects within it are also private. We only upload PDF and MP4 files.

I am able to download the PDF files from a Ruby application. However, when I try to download a video file, I only receive a 1 KB file. Can someone please help me identify what might be missing here?

I attempted to make the object public in the S3 bucket and then tried to download the video.

It successfully downloaded with the expected file size.